# Android: how to write NFC-V (ISO15693) tags on Nexus S?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, nexus-s, iso-15693

I'm trying to write a RFID tag on a Nexus S (Android 2.3.4) using the NFC-V technology. Using `transceive()` with a write single block command (0x21) invariably leads to a 
`java.io.IOException: transceive failed`

Both read multiple tags (0x22) and stay quiet (0x02) work flawlessly. I'm sure the tag is writable, since other devices can update it.
I tried both addressed and un-addressed mode, option flag set/unset, high/low data rate, but had no success.

Has anyone succeded in writing ISO15693 tags on the Nexus S? Any help would be *really* appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I had a similar problem with different tags (I had used a custom tag) and it was caused by timing problems, the phone gave up before the tag responded. I've never tried your type of tag before, but with my tag, other readers would work, even though the phone did not.

Answer (score 1):

I have a working app reading and writing custom ISO15693-compliant RFID-Tags.

Here are some hints to look into:

- Did you set the flags correctly? I am using 0x22 (addressed and high-speed)
- Did you include the UID when using addressed mode?

Also, could you please post the whole byte-array your are trying to send?

Comment: Hello Sege, thank you for your reply. I eventually managed to write a tag. It appears to be a hardware problem: I tried a different kind of Tag (with smaller antenna diameter), and it worked, albeit only at slow speed.  
This is the raw command I sent to the tag:  
2021eb650b3fcf2102e00012345678  
write single block, addressed, no option flag, slow speed    

Unfortunately the overall performance (write speed, reliability) is far from an usable system: 4-5 seconds to write 2048 bit tags, 20% failure rate under optimal conditions (tag actually touching the device, no relative movements).